# Redis cache server not running. Please contact Administrator / Tech support on bench serve --port 8001

Tags: redis, erpnext, frappe

Basically im working on frappe framework of python,
When i run “bench serve --port 8001” the server is started and im able to login too, but im getting an exception “Redis cache server not running. Please contact Administrator / Tech support”. But on “bench start” which by default start the server on port 8000, everything is working fine, im not getting any redis-server exception.
can anyone explain why its happening?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new bench using frappe, it will create a `Procfile` in the root folder. It includes web, redis, socket.io and redis workers.

```
$ cat Procfile 

redis_cache: redis-server config/redis_cache.conf
redis_socketio: redis-server config/redis_socketio.conf
redis_queue: redis-server config/redis_queue.conf

web: bench serve --port 8001

socketio: /Users/chillaranand/homebrew/bin/node apps/frappe/socketio.js

watch: bench watch

schedule: bench schedule
worker_short: bench worker --queue short 1>> logs/worker.log 2>> logs/worker.error.log
worker_long: bench worker --queue long 1>> logs/worker.log 2>> logs/worker.error.log
worker_default: bench worker --queue default 1>> logs/worker.log 2>> logs/worker.error.log
```

When users run `bench start` it will start 10 processes. All these processes are needed to run a frappe site smoothly.

When user runs `bench serve --port 80001`, it will start only web process and all other process are not started. Due to this, when web service tries to connect to redis, it is failing.

Users should always run `bench start` so that all processes will start.